# Getting nested array in checkbox input

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I am trying to get the nested array from a input value of a checkbox.
How do I handle a nested array?

These are the values:

```
const othersOptions = [
{procedure:'ORAL PROPHYLAXIS',price: 1000},
{procedure:'TOOTH RESTORATION',price:1200},
{procedure:'TOOTH EXTRACTION',price:800}
];
```

This is how I get the values from checkbox. I am guessing that `value={[item]}` is `procedure:'ORAL PROPHYLAXIS',price: 1000` **if the **ORAL PROPHYLAXIS** checkbox is checked**

```
                  <Form>
                    {othersOptions.map((item, index) => (
                      <div key={index} className="mb-3">
                        <Form.Check
                          value={[item]}
                          id={[item.procedure]}
                          type="checkbox"
                          label={`${item.procedure}`}
                          onClick={handleChangeCheckbox('Others')}
                          required
                        />
                      </div>
                    ))}
                  </Form>
```

When I console.log the value it shows that the value is `[Object object] this is the value`.

```
  const handleChangeCheckbox = input => event => {
    var value = event.target.value;
    console.log(value, "this is the value")
    var isChecked = event.target.checked;
    setChecked(current =>
      current.map(obj => {
        if (obj.option === input) {
          if(isChecked){
          return {...obj, chosen:  [{...obj.chosen, value}] };
          }else{
            var newArr = obj.chosen;
            var index = newArr.indexOf(event.target.value);
            newArr.splice(index, 1);
            return {...obj, chosen: newArr};
          }
        }
        return obj;
      }),
    );
    console.log(checked);
  }
```

and this is how I save the nested array:

```
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState([
    { option: 'Others',
      chosen: [],
  ]);
```

The reason why I need the procedure and price is so that I can save the values to MongoDB and get the values to another page which is a Create Receipt page. I want the following procedures price to automatically display in the Create Receipt page.Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is wondering how I fixed it.
I `stringfy` the input values and `parsed` the `e.target.values`

```
import "./styles.css";
import { Form } from "react-bootstrap";
import { useState } from "react";
import React from "react";

const othersOptions = [
  { procedure: "ORAL PROPHYLAXIS", price: 1000 },
  { procedure: "TOOTH RESTORATION", price: 1200 },
  { procedure: "TOOTH EXTRACTION", price: 800 },
  { procedure: "DEEP SCALING", price: 10200 },
  { procedure: "PTS AND FISSURES SEALANT", price: 700 },
  { procedure: "FLOURIDE TREATMENT", price: 5500 },
  { procedure: "INTERMEDIATE RESTORATION", price: 7000 },
  { procedure: "ORTHODONTICS", price: 48000 }
];

export default function App() {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState([{ option: "Others", chosen: [] }]);
  console.log(checked);
  const handleChangeCheckbox = (input) => (event) => {
    var value = JSON.parse(event.target.value);
    var isChecked = event.target.checked;
    console.log("value is:", value[0].procedure);
    var tempArr = { procedure: value[0].procedure, price: value[0].price };

    setChecked((current) =>
      current.map((obj) => {
        if (obj.option === input) {
          if (isChecked) {
            return { ...obj, chosen: [...obj.chosen, tempArr] };
          } else {
            var newArr = obj.chosen;
            var index = newArr.indexOf(event.target.value);
            newArr.splice(index, 1); // 2nd parameter means remove one item only
            return { ...obj, chosen: newArr };
          }
        }
        return obj;
      })
    );
  };

  return (
    <Form>
      {othersOptions.map((item, index) => (
        <div key={index} className="mb-3">
          <Form.Check
            value={JSON.stringify([item])}
            id={[item]}
            type="checkbox"
            label={`${item.procedure}`}
            onClick={handleChangeCheckbox("Others")}
            required
          />
        </div>
      ))}
    </Form>
  );
}
```

[RUN THE CODE HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-gould-2f92d4?file=/src/App.js:0-1858)